# Aliasing problem with pressure data

Tags: frequency, aliasing

I have done some pressure measurements of flowing air with transducers that had a frequency response of 5 kHz.

The data from these transducer was sampled also with 5 kHz and this is where my problem lies. After some research I gathered that the data from these transducers is probably completely aliased.

Is there a way to know which specific frequencies in the data have been aliased or has the complete data set been alterated?

Comment: How was the data sampled? And what do you mean by “*transducers that had a frequency response of 5 kHz.*”? Without an anti-aliasing filter, any frequency content $ \geq 2500 \texttt{Hz}$ will be aliased during sampling. If there was an anti-aliasing filter involved during sampling, you won’t have aliasing (or minimal aliasing), but also won’t have any frequency content past $2500 \texttt{Hz}$.

Comment: It was sampled via LabVIEW (I don't know if that helps). With 5 kHz frequency response I mean that the transducer is able to pick up pressure changes up to 5 kHz.
I don't know if LabVIEW automaticcaly implements an anti-aliasing filter, so let's just say that it does not, which means that there is aliasing.
Now I'm trying to figure out if all of the data is compromised or just specific parts.

Comment: You can assume that an anti-aliasing filter was in place unless you built your own ADC. My previous comment holds in each case. Can you do your measurements again? This time use a higher sampling rate! ($>10\texttt{kHz}$)

Answer (score 0):

> After some research I gathered that the data from these transducers is probably completely aliased.

How exactly did you gather this ? If you acquired the data with a half-way decent data acquisition system, there should have been an anti-aliasing filter in place and hence there should be no aliasing. The data should be lowpasses at 2 kHz or so, but anything below this should be fine.

> Is there a way to know which specific frequencies in the data have been aliased or has the complete data set been alterated?

If it actually IS aliasing (which is not likely), than chances are the whole data is compromised. It really depends on how signal energy is above 2.5 kHz and what shape that spectrum has there. Without knowing this, there is no way of determining what part of the spectrum is affected by aliasing and by how much.